# Is there a way to optimize below query used in h2 in mem database?

Tags: performance, h2

```
select MAX(column3) from table1 where column2 = ?
```

**Table schema:**

```
create table table1 (
    column1 varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    column2 varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    column3 int
)

create index on table1(column2,column3);
```

Size of my table increases gradually as day progress (~ 1 million at the end of day ) and where column2 = ? can result 20k rows.
H2 Version Used : 1.4.192

Comment: That looks like the best index your select should only read the records needed - what speed issues are you seeing. What does the profiler show? http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html#database_profiling

Comment: Average execution time of query is around ~400ms and I want to bring it down. I am using mutiple threads and queue is based on column2.